# 15% of total cost of sales

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

Having difficulties figuring out how to calculate 15%  of the total of the sales tables

This is what I've got so far (the sum). Finding difficulties displaying the total sales and also  15% of the sales in the same query..

```
SELECT SUM(prices) AS total sales FROM sales;
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(prices) AS total sales, SUM(prices)*0.15 as 15Percentsales FROM sales;

Answer (score 3):

You can just multiply the sum by 0.15:

```
SELECT SUM(prices) AS total_sales,
       SUM(prices) * 0.15 AS fifteen_percent
FROM   sales;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(prices) AS [total sales], ((15.0/100.0) * SUM(prices)) AS [15 percent of sales] FROM sales;
```